# HTML - Capture horizontal scroll event on Canvas when text too long

Tags: javascript, html

We are putting editable text on a canvas.  When I add a lot of characters beyond the width of the canvas, the canvas wants to scroll.  I want to prevent that scroll.

I think I want to capture the scroll with an event, and call preventDefault, or something.   We never want the canvas to scroll.

I cannot set the overflow property of the canvas to 'none', it needs to remain hidden so that elements that are off the canvas are hidden.

How can I capture this horizontal scroll event?  Thanks

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7503143/491897) contains info that may be useful to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the canvas element itself cannot scroll!!!!

i think you put the complete canvas into a div which can be scrolled. so you have to cancel Defaults on that div

Comment: show the html where the canvas is integrated, or link to page.